# Alternate mysql query for summing in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table that has the following fields:

```
date,amount,status
```

and I have a query that returns both the sum amount for each day (Quoted), as well as only the sum for a given status (SOLD).

It's very slow and I am trying to rewrite the query with no success.

The original query is:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) as Year,
    lpad(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), 2, 0) as Month,
    lpad(DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), 2, 0) as Day,
    (SELECT 
            sum(amount)
        FROM
            mytable
        where
            status = 'SOLD'
                and YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = Year
                and lpad(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), 2, 0) = Month
                and lpad(DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), 2, 0) = Day) as Sold,
    (SELECT 
            sum(amount)
        FROM
            mytable
        WHERE
            YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = Year
                and lpad(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), 2, 0) = Month
                and lpad(DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), 2, 0) = Day) as Quoted
FROM
    mytable
group by Year , Month , Day
```

The output looks like this (YYYY MM DD SUM):

```
2013      12         01           3442.00
```

Is there better way to write this so there it executes immediately? There are less than 10,000 records in the table.

Comment: For starters, i'd split up the date in year, month and day fields, since those are needed a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at least avoid subqueries

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) as Year,
    lpad(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), 2, 0) as Month,
    lpad(DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), 2, 0) as Day,
    SUM(case
        when status = 'SOLD' then amount
        else 0 end) Sold,
    sum(amount) as Quoted
from
    mytable
GROUP BY Year , Month , Day
```

Comment: That's spot on. Thanks Raphaël !